# Handling exception in another EJB method with transaction attribute REQUIRES_NEW

Tags: transactions, ejb, ejb-3.0

I have a EJB as below-

```
class ActivityProcessor{
     @Resource
     private SessionContext context;

     @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)
     public boolean processActivity(Activity activity) throws Exception{
          try{
             //required code for processing activity
          }catch(Exception ex){
            //Exception while processing activity
            handleException(ex,activity); 
            context.setRollbackOnly();
            throw ex;   
          }  
     } 

     @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)
     public void handleException(Exception ex, Activity activity)  {
          //Code to save this activity in exception table 
     }
}
```

We have a requirement in which, we want to save the activity in exception DB table if its processing fails.
But with above code, if there is exception in **processActivity**,  I am getting transaction timeout exception in **handleException** method.**handleException** is working fine individually.

Please suggest me if this issue of EJB transaction.

My understanding is,
1. New transaction will be created for processActivity

1. If there is exception in processActivity, handleException will be called.As the transaction attribute is REQUIRES_NEW, transaction of processActivity will be suspended & New transaction will be created for handleException
2. If handleException is successful, transaction of handleException will be saved.
3. Suspended transaction of processActivity will be resumed but due to 
   context.setRollbackOnly, it will be rolled back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You are calling `handleException` internally from `processActivity`, probably the container executes it with the same transaction & doesn't spawn a new one.
- Try to get reference through JNDI lookup or injection & then call `handleException` or move it to other bean.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the catch here is that you are invoking the `handleException` method *directly*. This way the application server has no chance to inject the transaction handling code.

Try to invoke the same method through the `EJBObject` exposed by the `SessionContext` as in:

```
class ActivityProcessor{
 @Resource
 private SessionContext context;

 @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)
 public boolean processActivity(Activity activity) throws Exception{
      try{
         //required code for processing activity
      }catch(Exception ex){
        //Exception while processing activity
        context.getBusinessObject(ActivityProcessor.class)
          .handleException(ex,activity); 
        context.setRollbackOnly();
        throw ex;   
      }  
 } 

 @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)
 public void handleException(Exception ex, Activity activity)  {
      //Code to save this activity in exception table 
 }
}
```